# Cannot pair two phones to one car

Tags: bluetooth

I have two phones (Samsung e5 and iPhone 6s) and two vehicles (2013 Subaru Impreza and 2015 Subaru Forester).
I tried pairing both phones in both cars (via the head unit and hands free) but cannot pair both phones. Best scenario is that one car takes the Samsung and the other the iPhone. I read somewhere that Subaru indicates that only 1 phone can be paired. Is that true? What is the procedure (if any) to solve the problem? Many thanks.

Comment: In the bluetooth settings, how many registered devices are there? Also, are you sure your phones are set to be discoverable? also do you expect both phones to connect at once? in which case this wont be the case, only one phone can be connected at any one time but a larger number may be paired.

Comment: i can only see 1 device

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [the manual](https://view.joomag.com/subaru-impreza-manuals-2013-impreza-owners-manual/0995966001386966207?page=249) for the 2013 Impreza says it is limited to one "registered (paired)" device. So for the Impreza you'll only be able to pair a single device.
For the [2015 Forester](https://view.joomag.com/subaru-forester-manuals-2015-forester-owners-manual/0978905001394119949?page=310) however, there is no notation about a pairing or registering limit, so you should be able to pair both devices to the Forester.

As Mauro noted in the comments, you won't be able to use both device at the same time, even if both are registered (paired). You can only get audio or phone functionality from a single device usually. My wife's car (2017 Accord and previously 2014 Civic) allow you to pair 1 device for phone functionality and 1 device for audio. So she could make and receive calls via the car using her phone, at the same time I could stream Pandora from my phone. It really depends on how the manufacturer programs (and also designs the circuitry for) the infotainment system.

Comment: tks for the insights. no am not planning to have both phones working at the same time. just need to have 1 phone programmed for both cars

Comment: In that case, just chose which phone and use it in bother cars. Start over and remove all pairing data from both phone and cars. As long as Subaru didn't do something ***really*** dumb, like giving the Bluetooth units the same name and is info, then it should work.

Comment: tks for the advise much appreciated